# Different between send() and sendTransaction()

Tags: contract-development, method

I'm wondering the difference between send() and sendTransaction() in web3. Take the following test code as example:

Contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract TestError {
    constructor() {}

    function method1(uint a) external pure {
        if (a <= 100) revert("value too small");
    }
}
```

Test file

```
it('common-test', async () => {
    let txHash    = null
    let accounts  = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
    let TestError = artifacts.require("TestError")
    let TestErrorDeployed = await TestError.deployed()

    let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(
        TestError.abi,
        TestErrorDeployed.address
    )
  
    await contract.methods.method1(10).send({
        from: accounts[0]
    }).on('transactionHash', (txHash) => {
        console.log("txHash: "+ txHash)
    }).on('error', (error) => {
        console.log("error: " + error)
    })
})
```

I can call the `method1` with `TestErrorDeployed.methods['method1(uint)'].sendTransaction()` or `contract.methods.method1(ARG).send()`.

What's the difference?

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: @JulissaDC The web3 nodejs module, version 1.7.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the use of `TestError.deployed()` in the code it seems you are mixing Truffle and web3.

For `sendTransaction` is a kinda of low level primitive. Usually it is not expected to be called by users. Instead you call the method directly: `instance.setValue(5)`, instead of `instance.setValue(5).sendTransaction()`.
See here the expected usage: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/v5.5.21/packages/contract#making-a-transaction-via-a-contract-function.

Web3js is a little more verbose `instance.methods.setValue(5).send()`. The behavior is exactly the same in both case a transaction is created and send to the blockchain, a *PromiEvent* is returned so you could wait until the transaction is mined.

web3js has another function [`sendTransaction()`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.4/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction) that works directly with addresses. For example when you want to make an ether transfer between accounts.